# OpenVPN: Allow access only for local connections (via OpenVPN)

Tags: networking, firewall, openvpn

I was recently assigned a task to do set up a secure development environment. I am thinking of doing the following:

1. Use OpenVPN to connect to the server.
2. Use firewall rules to block all incoming connections outside the local network
3. Services will include SHH, HTTP/HTTPS and git

Is this possible?

**UPDATE: I guess the more appropriate question is how to block access outside the local network.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be pretty easy with UFW.

Assuming your range is something like 192.168.1.x it would be something like

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 443
```

If you want to limit access to an exact IP address it would be something like

```
sudo ufw allow form xxx.xxx.x.x to any port 22
```

Basically just check out [UFW - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) and brush up on UFW.

Also, if you want to restrict access to VPN the ports are usually

```
 1701/tcp, 4500/udp, and 500/udp
```

but you may want to look that up to be sure

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicitly restrict "all incoming connections not originating from OpenVPN" ... you can restrict by port number, which often strongly correlates to the application - but there's no way for the local machine to know WITH ABSOLUTE CERTAINTY what the source of the connection is.  That said, since this stuff all runs under what are presumed to be relatively secure protocols, as long as you're following the other best practices like good passwords, etc then this is a pretty good start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the more appropriate question is how to block access outside the local network.